# Php Formmailer with extern wordfilter

Tags: php, forms, filter

I'm new into php and i don't know what to do, please help :D

```
     <?php
$blacklist = fopen ("blacklist.txt", "a+");
$PHP_SELF = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];

if (empty ($_POST['name']) == TRUE

or

empty ($_POST['id']) == TRUE

OR

empty ($_POST['baby']) == TRUE)

{

echo '<form id="begleiter" action="'. $PHP_SELF .'#begleiter" method="POST">';

if ($_POST['name'] == "") {

if ($_POST['gesendet'] == 1) {

echo "<i>Bitte gib deinen Namen an &hearts;</i><br>";}
}

echo '<table width="300"><tr><td><b>Name:</b></td> <td><input type="text" name="name" value="'.$_POST['name'].'"></td>';

if ($_POST['id'] == "") {

if ($_POST['gesendet'] == 1) {

echo "<i>Du hast deine ID vergessen &hearts;</i><br>";}
}

echo '<td><b>ID:</b></td> <td><input type="text" name="id" value="'.$_POST['id'].'"></td></tr>';

if ($_POST['baby'] == "") {

if ($_POST['gesendet'] == 1) {

echo "<i>Dein Baby brauch einen Namen!</i><br>";}
}

while ( $inhalt = fgets ($blacklist, 4096 ))
{
  $inhalt = trim ( $inhalt );

if ($_POST['baby'] == trim($inhalt)) {
if ($_POST['gesendet'] == 1) {
echo "<i>Der Name ist leider schon vergeben! Such dir bitte einen anderen aus!</i><br>";}
}

echo "$inhalt";
}

fclose($blacklist);

echo '<tr><td colspan="2" align="center"><b>Wie soll es heißen?:</b></td> <td colspan="2" align="center"><input type="text" name="baby" value="'.$_POST['baby'].'"></td></tr>';


echo '<input type="hidden" name="gesendet" value="1">';

echo '<tr><td colspan="4" align="center"><br><button type="submit" value=""></td></tr></table>
</form>';
}

else {
$message = 
"Name: ".$_POST['name']."\n".
"ID: ".$_POST['id']."\n".
"Baby: ".$_POST['baby'];

mail ("machina.maid@hotmail.de", "Baby", $message, "From: ".$_POST['name']);

echo "Danke für dein Formular, ".$_POST['name']."!";
}
```

this is my code, it's a formmailer and it works fine but the wordfilter...
as you can see there is a filter where the names in the extern file "blacklist.txt" should be sorted out and a message comes that the name is already given... my problem is, that i have to put something in the first if so that the form doesn't send the message off when there is a name in the input field that is written in the blacklist.txt... i don't know what to do! D: i wanted something what writes new names in the blacklist too but that didn't work out to xD but that's not that important!

thanks beforehand! (and sry for my english :/)

Comment: Could you please give a smaller example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose the blacklist email addresses. One address on one line:

```
email@email.com
email2@email.com
```

This loads the file contents into a variable:

```
$blacklist = file_get_contents('blacklist.txt');
```

Because each address on one line, it is easy to get into the array:

```
$blacklistArray = explode("\n", $blacklist);
```

Now you can check whether the address is in the array:

```
in_array('email@email.com', $blacklistArray);
```